# RemoteWebDriver causing stackoverflow error when calling switchTo() method

Tags: selenium, stack-overflow, xvfb, remotewebdriver

Selenium Version: 3.7.1

I am automating a java swing application and making use of remote web driver as follows:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setBrowserName("java");
dc.setVersion(" ");
dc.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
dc.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
javaDriverTest = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("docker container url"), dc);
```

Everything works fine apart from the following:

```
javaDriverTest.switchTo().window(windowName);
```

and I subsequently get this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.fillInputBuffer(BHttpConnectionBase.java:344)
    at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.isStale(BHttpConnectionBase.java:364)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.isStale(CPoolProxy.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:208)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:657)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getWindowHandles(RemoteWebDriver.java:505)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:962)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:963)
```

This doesn't happen all the time. But is quite frequent. Any idea how it can potentially be fixed?

Comment: how are you using "river.switchTo().window(windowName);" ?

Comment: Can you just fix the code that is causing that error?

Comment: @cruisepandey I have edited the original question to add more info. Please have a  look.

Comment: @SiKing, its simply a switchTo().window() call. I can't think of any kind of fix for that call in particular. Perhaps I need to find an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is related to the way I started up the application i.e. I initially used the following:

```
export DISPLAY=:1.0
javaws -J -Dmarathon.agent=file:/root/Downloads/marathon-java-agent-5.1.4.0.jar.........
```

but when I added Xvfb to the command i.e.

```
Xvfb :1.0
export DISPLAY=:1.0
javaws -J -Dmarathon.agent=file:/root/Downloads/marathon-java-agent-5.1.4.0.jar.........
```

it fixed the issue. Therefore, I believe this issue is indeed not related to RemoteWebDriver, but actually to way the application under test is started.